# Delete files in folder with foreach loop

Tags: php, file, foreach, yii2, delete-file

**In a file called docs.php I have made the following code to display all the files inside uploads folder**

**The foreach() loops all the files there stored in a view of the website and has an hyperlink that let it be open in the browser (in my model file it has restriction's to only pds, png or jpg files)**

What i'm not able to do is inside the foreach() loop for every iteration is display some sort of hyperlink (example: Delete me!) that permits the user to click and delete only that particular file physical from the server, the others not clicked must remain visible.

**My php code inside a view to the forloop() is:**

```
<?php
        $files=\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('uploads/', ['except'=>['*.DS_Store']]);
        if (isset($files[0])) {
            foreach ($files as $index => $file) {
                $nameFile = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
                echo Html::a($nameFile, Url::base().'/uploads/'.$nameFile) . "<br/>" . "<br/>" ; // render do ficheiro no browser
            }
        } else {
            echo "There are no files available for download.";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you able to delete those files without using foreach loop ?

Comment: I don´t think so, since i didn't create a blob file in my database. I only validate and save the files inside uploads folder and then loop through them with the foreach loop to display inside a view.

Answer (score 1):

As i assume you have concept of FileHelper, but to delete file you have to use php native function unlink(filePath). [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: Thank's. I'll see what i can do with that tip.

Comment: Now it deletes all files inside the folder, because my unlink function is used inside the foreach loop.